# MongoDb- distance calculation between two coordinates

Tags: mongodb

When I am firing this query on MongoDB, I am getting all the places in the proximity of specified co-ordinates `{ "coordinates", new BsonArray { longitude, latitude } }` within `maxDistanceInKm`.

```
BsonDocument geoNearStep = new BsonDocument {
    { "$geoNear", new BsonDocument {
        { "near", new BsonDocument {
            { "type", "Point" },
            { "coordinates", new BsonArray { longitude, latitude } }
        }},
        { "spherical", true },
        { "query", andQuery},
        { "limit", 200 },
        { "maxDistance", maxDistanceInKm * 1000 },
        { "distanceField", "Location.distance" }
    }}
};
```

Now I want to use the result locations and calculate the distance of each of these from another co-ordinates which I have as `{ "NewCoordinates", new BsonArray { NewLongitude, NewLatitude } }`.

I'm not sure how to query MongoDb to have it calculate the individual distances for locations found in query from the new co-ordinates. Please advise.

Comment: So let me get this correctly. You want to find locations within some distance from a point, then calculate the distance of those points to another location? I don't think you can do this all in MongoDB currently. Why not do the 2nd comparison in the application? Just make sure that you're using the proper geodesic calculation, though.

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes that requirement is correct (Odd, I know) but apparently I need to calculate the distance from a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't possible in current versions of MongoDb and we ended up implementing it in .net side.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "distance": {
            "$multiply": [
                {
                    "$radiansToDegrees": {
                        "$acos": {
                            "$add": [
                                {
                                    "$multiply": [
                                        {
                                            "$sin": {
                                                "$degreesToRadians": "$lat2"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$sin": {
                                                "$degreesToRadians": "$lat1"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$multiply": [
                                        {
                                            "$cos": {
                                                "$degreesToRadians": {
                                                    "$subtract": [
                                                        "$lng2",
                                                        "$lng1"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$cos": {
                                                "$degreesToRadians": "$lat2"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$cos": {
                                                "$degreesToRadians": "$lat1"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                111.18957696
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).